# where does windows store icloud drive files created from an iPad?

Tags: windows, data-recovery, icloud

The MacOS stores `icloud drive` files locally in `~/Library/Mobile Documents`.

Where does windows7 store icloud drive files by default? I had not customized the location while installing it in my windows machine.

I accidentally deleted icloud files in ipad. The files were synched between my windows7 laptop and ipad with icloud. When deleted from ipad, it was removed in windows too. When I used recovery tool (Dr fone) for ipad, it only recovered photos, contacts and bookmarks, but not the word documents. When I used recovery tool (R-studio and Recuva) in windows machine with magnetic disk, I could get all other old deleted files but icloud file.

Recovery software in windows find too many other files, but not icloud drive file when scanned `c:\`. May be I am searching in in wrong location.

Can anyone suggest where do I need to look and how to look?

Comment: I don't have iCloud drive on a PC here, but usually, that kind of data would be in %appdata% (C:users/[yourname]/AppData/Roaming/ if you need to go the long way)